# Are these confidence intervals calculated correctly?

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation

Is the 1SD calculation correct in this image? Instead of 16% for 1SD on each side of the mean, they have 34%.

SD2 and SD3 are correct. SD2=100-95 = 5%. Divide by 2 = 2.5%. and same for SD3 = 99.7% (.15%).

[image]

Comment: Looks correct to me. 16% are *more* than 1 SD away from the mean on each side: 50-34 = 16.

Comment: I see what I did wrong. 16% is actually on the tails > SD1 (13.5 + 2.35 + .15). Am I correct to say that the probability of fall below 1SD is 16% and below 2SD is 2.5%?

Comment: Yes, that seems correct to me.